# androidMainfest.xml file error in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

"Element androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat must be declared" this error is shown when I run the xml file in android studio. there is no suggestions to change the code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="QUANTITY"
    android:padding_top="16dp"
    android:padding_bottom="16dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text-view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layuout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PRICE"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="ORDER"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
```

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

Comment: add some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you placed your layout xml files in the wrong directory.
The right folder is `res/layout`.
Check [App resource overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) documentation.

[image]

Comment: I am editing "AndroidMainfest.xml" file in android studio. Is that correct???

Comment: Your LinearLayoutCompat should not be placed in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but in a separate xml file in the `res/layout` folder. The manifest file is only for general project configurations.

Comment: I think i edited the wrong xml generated file on android studio.Can you please guide me through it as I am new to android.

Comment: android studio didn't generate a res/layout folder . I think i must have selected no activity option while creating the project.Shall i create a new project file?

Comment: Create a new one with the "Empty activity" option, don't edit the `AndroidManifest.xml`, and create all your layouts under `res/layout`. I edited my answer with a screenshot of the folder.